# Gravity Forms Salesforce field mapping for custom objects

Tags: plugins

I'm using the [Gravity Forms plugin](http://www.gravityforms.com/) on my site, along with the [Gravity Forms Salesforce plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/gravity-forms-salesforce/), which connects the forms to Salesforce. I can set a dropdown box to populate with choices from Salesforce, but I don't see how to let it use custom objects. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Nope, never did. I'm thinking of switching over to web-to-lead forms from salesforce.

Comment: I actually got this working using a custom function, it gathers information from a custom post type then sends it to salesforce with the SOAP client. I can do the same now with any form system, if you want help send me an email http://bit.ly/UHR2WS